# How to disable/remove outlook on windows xp professional?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a windows xp machine which has been installed with Microsoft Office 2007. I would like to disable the outlook access only for other admin/power users on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only thought on this is to password protect your .pst file, I'm not even sure if you can do that in 2007.

This method works in 2003, hopefully 2007 is the same:

Open outlook, right click on your personal folder, select properties, select advanced, change password. Your original password is probably blank, enter a new password and verify. Now whenever you open Outlook it will prompt you for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain correctly? You want to remove Outlook Express/ Outlook 2010 for certain people only or everyone?
For everyone:
For Outlook Express it's listed in Control Panel/ Add or Remove Component / Add Remove Windows component and in the list uncheck Outlook express.
For Outlook, the easiest way is to rerun the Office setup, choose to customize the install and remove outlook.
For specific users it could be difficult